# Only allow one pin drop

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app and im following a online course to show how to drop pins on the map but that lets you drop an infinite amount of pins. I only want 1 pin to be dropped at a time, for example if you drop a pin at this location then drop a pin at another it removes original pin

Here is my code so far

```
let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "mapLongPress:")
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 2
    self.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)




func mapLongPress(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer){
    print("its done")

    let touchedAt = recognizer.locationInView(self.mapView)
    let touchedAtCoordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D = mapView.convertPoint(touchedAt, toCoordinateFromView: self.mapView)
    let newPin = MKPointAnnotation()
    newPin.coordinate = touchedAtCoordinate
    mapView.addAnnotation(newPin)
}
```

Comment: You can try clearing the mapview before drawing the next pin. In the long press gesture clear the annotations from the map.

Comment: You can remove all annotations before dropping another pin. mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks, worked perfectly....basically i want to sent the dropped pins location to parse...so you def helped me on that path!!!

Comment: @MatthewSingleton if you want me to post my comment as an answer please let me know :)

Comment: id love to give you the credit, please go ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all annotations before dropping another pin.

```
mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont create a new pin each time, just update the coordinates for the pin

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct way but anytime I need to show a new pin or annotation on the map I clear the old one.

```
[self.mapView removeAnnotations:[self.mapView annotations]];
```

Sorry havent got the code in swift but it works for me as I need to show vehicle icon on map and every 30 sec it shows the new position. Hope this helps.